# How to show Rails' Jobs logs in Heoku Local?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails 5.0.2 application I use logger inside controllers and they are shown in the Heroku Local console without issues. But logs don't show for `logger` commands inside ActiveJob jobs. I have tried with `Rails.logger` and different levels (error, warn, etc).

How can I show logs from jobs in Heroku Local?

Comment: What is your log level? Try to puts `Rails.logger.level`

Comment: `puts Rails.logger.level` outputs 0

Comment: Did you try to use `Rails.logger.info 'message'` in ActiveJob ?